# SELECT TOP error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have this mySQL script:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM produse ORDER BY `id_produs` DESC
```

Generates this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2 * FROM produse ORDER BY `id_produs` DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How hard can it be to look this up in the manual?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

there is no TOP in mysql

use LIMIT 2

```
   SELECT * FROM produse ORDER BY id_produs DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `LIMIT` instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   produse
ORDER  BY id_produs DESC
LIMIT  2
```